# Java Coding--Inheritance Issues

Tags: java, inheritance

I am new to java and am having a lot of issues making a multilevel inheritance program.

I'm trying to make a program where my main class (AU) is broken down into subclasses depending on what the user types.

My issue is when I try to call my second level (Part_Time_Student) subclass from my first level subclass (Student).

Whenever I try to call it, it just recalls the first level subclass(the one I'm currently in).

I noticed that if I make my second level subclass(Part_Time_Student) extend the main superclass(AU) it works, but I would prefer to make it extend student.

I realize this is a very complicated post (especially since I don't know the terminology), but I hope my code is easy enough to follow.

**AU.java**

```
public class AU {
    Scanner input;
    static String name;
    static Long numb;    

public AU() {

}

public void Name() {
        input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the member's name");
        String nam = input.nextLine();
        AU.name=nam;
        System.out.println(nam +" has been added");         
}

public void Phone() {
    input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the member's phone number");
    Long number = input.nextLong();
    AU.numb=number;
    System.out.println(number+ " has been saved");
}
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AU au = new AU();
        au.Name();
        au.Phone();        
        while (3==3) {
            System.out.println("What is your role at the University?");
            input=new Scanner(System.in);
            String determ=input.nextLine();
        if (determ.toUpperCase().equals("STUDENT")) {
            Student student=new Student();
            break;
        }
        else if (determ.toUpperCase().equals("STAFF")) {
            break;
        }
        else if (determ.toUpperCase().equals("FACULTY")) {
            break;
        }
        else if (determ.toUpperCase().equals("TESTER")) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Response");

        }
        }
        System.out.println("yay");
}}
```

**Part_Time_Student.java**

```
public class Part_Time_Student extends Student {

    public Part_Time_Student() {
        System.out.println("it switched");
        System.out.println(GPA);
        System.out.println(Assign);
        System.out.println(name);
    }
        public void tester() {
        System.out.println("test");
        }
    }
```

**Student.java**

```
public class Student extends AU {
    static double GPA=5;
    static String Assign;
    public Student() {
        super();
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println("Are you a full-time student or part-       student(type part or full)");
        input=new Scanner(System.in);
        while (3==3) {
            String get=input.nextLine();
            switch (get.toUpperCase()) 
            {
            case "PART":{
                Student.Assign="Part";
                Part_Time_Student Studentp = new Part_Time_Student();
                break;
            }
            case "FULL":{
                Student.Assign="Full";
                break;
            }
            default :{
                System.out.println("Invalid ");

            }}}
    }
        public void gpa(String grade,long credits) {

            System.out.println(name+numb);

        name=name;
    }
    public void Welcome() {
        System.out.println("Welcome Student");      
    }
}
```

Output:
What is the member's name

-Test

Test has been added

What is the member's phone number

-540

540 has been saved

What is your role at the University?

-student

Test

Are you a full-time student or part-student(type part or full)

-part

Test

Are you a full-time student or part-student(type part or full)

As you can see the command "Part_Time_Student Studentp = new Part_Time_Student();" is just recalling the student class over an over.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? It seems like you are trying to use inheritance for the sake of it, and it's not immediately clear from your example why? When you say "Whenever I try to call it, it just recalls the first level subclass" - remember, subclasses inherit from their parents, so unless you're overriding methods in subclasses, calling an inherited method from a parent will invoke it on the parent.

Comment: What print statements you are getting on console?

Comment: I am doing an inheritance program for my class, so I'm trying to use it as much as possible (even though it is not always necessary). Anyway, the output I'm getting is: (Going to put in original post)

Comment: Is there a reason you have the infinite while loop in your Student constructor?

Comment: He's breaking it after reading a successful line @SpencerBrett, so it's not an infinite while loop. However, I'm not sure why he is doing `3 == 3`, instead of just writing `true` in the parenthesis.

Comment: It seems that you may also have some issues with the static variables you are using (which are not inherited) in your Student constructors.

Comment: @RileyCarney, Don't those break statements apply to the switch and not the while loop?

Comment: Yeah my intention was to make a loop until a correct value is put in. Could you elaborate on static variables not being inherited? My name variable seems to be inheriting, but as I said I'm completely new to java

Comment: When you access a static variable, it belongs to the class that declared it. Static variables can be "hidden" in subclasses by declaring another static variable that has the same name as the super class.

Comment: @SpencerBrett I'm blind

Comment: @circask8ers If you assign to a static variable in a subclass, you are actually changing it in the super class. [Example](http://ideone.com/q74Jrg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your statement `Part_Time_Student Studentp = new Part_Time_Student();` out of while loop, infact out of the constructor.
When you are constructing your Student class, and inside when you invoke a constructor of subclass, it in turn calls its super class which is Student, so it goes over and over. So it will keep asking you same question again and again.

Remove the `Part_Time_Student` constructor from :

```
case "PART":{
        Student.Assign="Part";
        // Part_Time_Student Studentp = new Part_Time_Student(); //remove this
        break;
    }
```

Change this if condition in your Main class below to:

```
if (determ.toUpperCase().equals("STUDENT")) 
{
   Student student=new Student();
   if ( student.Assign.equalsIgnoreCase( "Part" ) )
   {
      Part_time_Student part_time_student = new Part_time_Student();
   }
   break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! The only problem now is it prints/requests input twice before going to Part_Time_Student. Is there a way I can make it so you only have to type your student status once?

Comment: I think I figured it out, but let me know if there is a better solution. 
        `public Student() {
 }
 public void run() {
   System.out.println(name);
   System.out.println("Are you a full-time student or part-student(type part or full)");
   input=new Scanner(System.in);
   
   String get=input.nextLine();
   switch (get.toUpperCase()) 
   {
   case "PART":{
    Student.Assign="Part";
    System.out.println("Set");
    break;`

Comment: You need to re-think about the design, don't get inputs in your constructors. After you construct the object, then get input from user. So move the question "Are you full time... " from the constructor of Student and put it after Student student = new Student(); in your Main. Then depending on user input, you can call new Part_time_Student ()

Comment: Alright, I'll go ahead and make those changes. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: If you can, you can mark either this or the below one as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html